# Does Intellij Idea have instant run?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

It is some time now since I first heard about instant run in Android Studio 2.0. Is it ever coming to IntelliJ Idea? I have 2016.1.2 and still nothing. I can imagine it can speed up development. I am still tearing my hair every time I press run...

Couldn't find any valuable information about this online. All what google finds is just "IntelliJ and Android Studio is made on the same code base" I guess it is more complicated than that.

Comment: "Instant run"?   Why ask here?  Sounds like it'd be better for JetBrains new feature requests.

Comment: @duffymo It should be in IntelliJ read edited answer

Comment: I couldn't find it in IntelliJ proper or as a plug in.  When it says "Google based Android Studio on IntelliJ", it makes me think Google added it to Android Studio, but JetBrains didn't fold it into IntelliJ.  Shouldn't be difficult to ask for the new feature.

Comment: From the completely separate Android developer studio web site: "On top of IntelliJ's powerful code editor and developer tools, Android Studio offers even more features".  Key phrase - on top of.  Not part of IntelliJ.  So it's worth it to ask IntelliJ if they plan to absorb that change or include it as a plug in.  You're welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it's going to be released in Intellij 2016.2

Quoting [2016.2 EAP Release Notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.2+EAP):

> - Android
>
>   - [Android Studio 2.0 features](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html).

Edit:

Looks like it was eventually released and made production ready in Intellij 2017.1

Quoting the [What's New page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2017-1-java):

> Instant run
>
> This release adds many stability and reliability improvements to
>   Instant Run. If you have previously disabled Instant Run, the Android
>   team encourages you to re-enable it.

Answer (score 4):

No. From [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 Notes](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/07/intellij-idea-2016-2-is-here/):

> Android
>
> The update includes the Android Studio 2.0 features: faster Emulator, experiment GPU Debugger, faster full builds, and code generation and testing for App Indexing. **Note, Instant Run is not fully-merged yet.**